# Backport of hook_library() for Drupal 6?

Tags: 6, hooks

I've come to love the [hook_library()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_library/7) of Drupal 7 as an extremely clean way of including assets etc. I'm fully aware of the many different ways to include assets intelligently (including the context_addassets module) but I'd love a near exact drop in backport for the `hook_library()` that Drupal 7 provides.

Note: Using `mymodule_library()` essentially defines a list of css/js (and their dependant libraries) which can be added in one simple call to [drupal_add_library()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_library/7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module that originated the patch that introduced `hook_library()` in Drupal 7 is the [jQ](http://drupal.org/project/jq) module (see [Allow to add JS/CSS libraries (sets of files, settings, and dependent libraries](http://drupal.org/node/315100)). The hooks used by that module are different, but that is the module that is closer to what you are looking for. That module requires you to call a different function, but using `drupal_add_js()` would require you to hack the Drupal core, which is something it is never suggested to do, in the cases where you want absolute compatibility between Drupal 6 and Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [Libraries API](http://drupal.org/project/libraries) module available for Drupal 6 which is similar to the native Drupal 7 hook_libraries.

Comment: This is good for global libraries that are shared between modules but I was really looking for a simple way to add a group of single module assets (css/js) in one call vs many.

Comment: In that case I'd use kiamlalunos suggestion. jQ allows you to dump the files in a plugins folder then call them via jq_add('library.js'). A little known feature is that if you have a css file make sure it's the same name as the js library (e.g. library.css) and in the same folder and it will be including in the same call.